# In Mysql Workbench, where is Synchronize Model with Database

Tags: sync, mysql, database, mysql-workbench, schematic

As displayed in Mysql [Database Synchronization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-synchronization.html) documentation.

I cannot find this particular `Synchronize Model with Database` window / wizard under `Database ->`

I have Mysql Workbench 6.0.9.11421 build 1170 Community Edition

Answer (score 2):

With your model open (this is required, as the navigation menus are context-aware), choose either "Synchronize Model" or "Synchronize with Any Source" under "Database".